# Creating tinder like card layout using UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tinder

I am trying to recreate the tinder card stack which can then be swiped through. I have decided to do this using UIcollectionView.

I was going to make an array of user objects and within each, there would be an array of images. So for the number of sections, I would say arr.count and for the number of sub-sections arr[section].arrImg.count.

Currently, I have a problem where when I run the project I get a vertical stack of 5 images. I assume each image represents one cell. But I need these cells to be stacked on top of each other like tinder.

**How can I do that (stacked on top of each other like tinder)?**

The logic for making the card layout:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(peopleArr[section].arrOfProfileImages.count, "jfldhsajklfhsdkj")
    return peopleArr[section].arrOfProfileImages.count
}


//This current version loads all people it should only return like 3...
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    print("fkhdsgafhjdgsajhfgdsak", peopleArr.count)
    return peopleArr.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! DatingCardCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ProfileImage")//peopleArr[indexPath.row].arrOfProfileImages[indexPath.section]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@phillfarrugia/building-a-tinder-esque-card-interface-5afa63c6d3db

Comment: @matt I have seen that before. The issue is that the auto layout is complicated with that.

Comment: Well you won’t achieve it with a flow layout as you are attempting to do. That is impossible. If you insist on using a collection view you would have to write a custom layout. And that is even harder.

Comment: @matt ok I will see how I can make the way you mentioned work.

Comment: You might like to delete the question, if you've found the way forward.

Comment: Maybe you can check this out https://github.com/mac-gallagher/Shuffle